# How to generate cryptographically strong pseudorandom data very rapidly?

Tags: cryptography, openssl, random, entropy

What's the best way to go about generating a fast stream of cryptographically strong pseudorandom data without installing uncommon packages?  Drawing from /dev/urandom is far too slow.

I had an idea from reading the 'wipe' manpage:

> will use the fresh RC6 algorythm as a PRNG; RC6 is keyed with the 128-bit seed, and then a null block is repeatedly encrypted to get the pseudo-random stream.

Encrypting a null block with only a single key is probably not the best idea, especially when large amounts of pseudorandom data are required, so I quickly made this in bash:

```
while dd if=/dev/zero bs=$(shuf -n 1 -i 1024-67108864) count=1 2>/dev/null | openssl aes-256-cbc -nosalt -k "$(head -c 32 < /dev/random)"; do :; done > [whateverneedsrandomness]
```

This encrypts a stream of zeros with a random 32 byte seed.  The stream is reseeded on average every 32 MB (the range is between 1 KB and 64 MB with a resolution of one byte).  The reseed interval is random to prevent anyone from guessing where a new key is used.  I purposefully chose CBC as the block mode instead of CTR even though it's faster because I've read that CTR is only good for constant streams, and my very limited cryptographic knowledge tells me that a repeating counter that restarts all the time isn't a good idea when the "stream" will only be a few MB long, although I really don't know for sure.

One worry I have is whether or not the stream leaving openssl is fully encrypted.  If the input is not evenly divisible by the block size, would openssl leave the extra data blank (leaving "gaps" of 0s scattered throughout the resulting stream)?  Does [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) have anything to do with that?

So my question is, is this a good way to create fast random data?  And is there anything I missed/overlooked, etc, such as using the wrong blockmode?

Comment: [Dave, haven't seen you in a while!](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/880/the-memes-of-information-security/1132#1132)

Comment: If you use a 64 bit counter, the counter will not restart in any amount of time you're willing to wait for.

Comment: Cryptographically secure PRNGs have [unique constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator). Otherwise I'd just recommend a fast PRNG like `x * x | 5`.

Comment: Unless you need special properties, like forward secrecy or recovery from compromise any fast stream cipher will do. On a machine with AES-NI, AES-CTR is extremely fast, on other machines I'd consider ChaCha with either 20 or 12 rounds.

Comment: @Lucas
I understand that homebrew crypto is very bad practise, but I need to be able to generate a lot of secure random bytes rapidly, I have no other alternative.  The only thing that's really "homebrew" about this is the random reseed interval, because even /dev/urandom is designed to be reseeded at a certain rate.

Comment: @CodesInChaos
Is AES-CTR really going to be secure for an unlimited amount of pseudorandom data?  If that's the case then why don't all computers use just one initial key and then the rest of /dev/random is from the cipher?

Comment: For forward secrecy you need to introduce an irreversible operation from time to time and for recovery from compromise one needs to mix in new randomness. But in principle you can emit unlimited amounts of secure pseudo-random-data at the speed of a fast stream cipher.

Comment: `openssl aes-128-ctr -nosalt -in /dev/zero -pass file:/dev/urandom`. Just do something as simple as that. Fast, cryptographically secure way to write random data to stdout.

Answer (score 11):

**Edit:** The obviousness was blinding so I missed it. OpenSSL already offers an interface to its own internal PRNG, which is seeded with the machine's `/dev/urandom`, but then extends it with its own crypto. Just do this:

```
openssl rand 10000000
```

to produce 10 millions of pseudo-random bytes. On my laptop, this appears to be about 3 times faster than `/dev/urandom`, i.e. 11 MByte/s or so. If this is not fast enough for you, read on.

---

**Original response:**

It really depends on the involved hardware and context. Since you are talking about a bash script, `/dev/urandom` and OpenSSL, I suppose that:

- You use Linux.
- You want to produce a big *file* full of pseudorandom bytes.
- You want a solution which is a scripted assembly of existing, "normal" packages, not a programmatic solution.

Indeed, if you could write your own C code, your best options would be either AES encryption in CTR mode with the [AES-NI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) instructions (on recent PC which offer these instruction), or a dedicated stream cipher (e.g. one of [these](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/)). On a 2.4 GHz Core2 CPU, I could get 700 MByte/s of pseudorandom bytes out of Sosemanuk. I hereafter suppose that you are limited to scripts.

Using OpenSSL encryption is not a bad idea, but there are details:

- Randomizing the length of each chunk is a useless complication.
- There is no need to go to AES-256; AES-128 is already fine. AES-256 is 40% slower than AES-128, and adds no practical improvement in security.
- When encrypting a long sequence of zeros with CBC, you are actually running the block cipher in OFB mode (encrypt a block, encrypt it again, and again, and again). This is reasonable as long as you remain below the *2<sup>n/2</sup>* limit, meaning that with AES (128-bit blocks) you don't use a chunk longer than *2<sup>64</sup>* 16-byte blocks, i.e. 250 millions of terabytes. Chances are that you won't reach it anyway. In that sense, the "reseeding" is not really needed.
- When you "reseed" (if you decide to maintain this feature, which is not necessary), use `/dev/urandom`, not `/dev/random`. `/dev/urandom` is fine for cryptography (the OS boot scripts ensure that the internal PRNG is properly seeded), despite the misguided paranoid qualms of the `/dev/random` implementation. On the other hand, `/dev/random` may block, and thus be *really* slow (nothing is slower than a blocked process).
- Beware of strings. `bash` uses character strings; `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` return *bytes*, including bytes of value 0. This may result in an artificially truncated key, and lowered security. This is bad. Instead, you should encode the bytes in hexadecimal and the the `-K` and `-iv` command-line arguments with `openssl`.
- OpenSSL may add a header which begins with 8 fixed bytes (thus totally non-random). It does not do so if you use `-K` and `-iv`.
- OpenSSL will also use some padding so you will get an extra 16-byte block at the end (this is not a problem; the padding is on the cleartext, and encryption "randomizes" it).

This leads to the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
key=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16 count=1 2>/dev/null | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1)
iv=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16 count=1 2>/dev/null | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1)
dd if=/dev/zero bs=65536 count=8192 2>/dev/null | openssl aes-128-cbc -K $key -iv $iv
```

When invoked, this script outputs a sequence of exactly 536870928 pseudorandom bytes, which are fit for cryptographic purposes. Feel free to modify the `bs` and `count` parameters, but remember that `dd` will allocate a RAM buffer of size `bs`, so you usually want to keep `bs` small, but not too small to avoid too many roundtrips into the kernel (8192 to 65536 are usually good values).

I use MD5 here only for the convenience of the bytes-to-hexadecimal conversion (the known shortcomings of MD5 have no influence whatsoever on the security in this case).

This script should work on any decent Linux installation. It uses only packages which should be there by default. On my not-very-powerful laptop, this script produces pseudorandom bytes at the rate of 73 MBytes per second, which is not bad and probably enough for your purposes (if that is not enough, then you will probably have other issues with I/O bottlenecks).

Comment: Does `/dev/urandom` produce less than 73 MB/s for you? Is it significantly slower than its windows equivalent? I don't have linux at hand to test myself, but `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` produces 128 MB/s for me (22.5 cpb).

Comment: Oh yes, `/dev/urandom` is abysmally slow. It tops at about 3.6 MB/s on my machine, 20 times slower than my OpenSSL-powered script. I suppose that this speed is still enough for most purposes, but indeed this does not look very good.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice I kept /dev/random in there.  I only use /dev/random because I have HAVEGE installed, which speeds up /dev/random quite a bit.  As for the key being artificially truncated, that's not a problem.  I tested it and bash variables, head, and openssl can accept any character even if it's not unicode.  Also, I am aware of openssl rand, it's not fast enough.

Comment: Yu probably don't need to use `dd`, `md5sum`, and `cut` twice just to get the key and IV. You should be able to do `-pass file:/dev/urandom` and get the equivalent amount of randomness. Also, I don't think openssl adds a header (if you mean the IV). If I recall, the IV is deterministically derived from the key, so two invocations with the same `-k` will have the same key _and_ IV.

Comment: @forest: `enc -pass file:` stops at the first null or newline, which could be as little as zero bytes. The header mentioned by The Furry One is the literal string `Salted__` (followed by the salt value which is _usually_ random) at the beginning of `enc` ciphertext when password-based (not `-K`) and salted (either default random or `-S` but not `-nosalt`). For password-based both key and IV (if used) are derived from the password (which _can_ be `-k` lowercase) and usually salt, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption

Comment: ... although if the key is random and thus almost certainly unique, you might as well use a fixed IV like `-iv 00`. (I'm pretty sure we have a Q on that, but I can't find it.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Oh good to know! I thought `enc -pass file:` stopped after exactly 32 bytes (for a 256-bit key).

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself often depleting the random data source, I would advise you investing in a hardware random number generator such as http://www.entropykey.co.uk/.

You are typically limited to the amount of random data that can be generated by the random number generator hardware on your CPU. External devices such as these can generate good random data at a much faster rate.

Comment: `/dev/urandom` doesn't block because it "depleted the random data source". So if it's too slow, that's just because the implementation is slow. You only need true entropy at low rates to ensure security (a few hundred bits after startup, cloning a VM, restoring the OS from backup etc.) and possible occasionally to recover from pool compromise (dubious gain IMO)

Comment: It blocks when it exhausts the buffered pool of random data and reaches a critical point where it must obtain entropy from `/dev/random`, no? I am assuming this user wants strong entropy which is why they use `/dev/random` in their example in the first place... I suppose it is down to the asker whether they are satisfied, I'm providing this answer in case they were not aware of such devices.

Comment: AFAIK only `/dev/random` blocks due to "entropy exhaustion", which IMO is a concept with little relevance to actual security. If you use a truly random 32 byte seed you can produce unlimited amounts of secure pseudo random data. The only thing that such a construction is lacking is recovering from compromise and support for state cloning/roleback.

Comment: @CodesInChaos *"you can produce unlimited amounts of secure pseudo random data"* can obscure the fact that PRNGs are inferior to TRNGs ([note 1](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/726), [note 2](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10776)); which is why Unix operating systems provide both `random` and `urandom` options - `random` can be derived from TRNG sources and if those sources are slow, hungry consumers of CSRNGs can exhaust the available entropy - typically a metric determined by the `random` driver and pre-set by mathematicians for the TRNG.

Comment: @LateralFractal The difference between a proper PRNG seeded with 32 bytes of true random data and a TRNG does not matter in practice. David Schwartz [put it like this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/76822/i-need-a-true-random-number-generator-web-service/100826#100826): "What you are asking for is Holy water, and you are rejecting the suggestion that you use regular water. The only reason for preferring Holy water over water is religious. There are simple, randomly-seeded PRNGs that cannot be distinguished from true physical randomness by any known process."

Comment: @CodesInChaos Is there a point you are trying to make other than conflating maths and applied computing? There is a reason why `/dev/random` exists; and while you may personally consider it a pointless reason - the option still exists and should exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, the entropykey.co.uk website says that the device - which sounds like a nice one - is not in stock, that there is a "very long waiting period" for more, and they don't have a projected date when they will be available again. (see http://www.entropykey.co.uk/shop/)

Comment: @LateralFractal: Would there be any difference between a TRNG and a quality PRNG that was seeded with 32 bytes of random data and had its internal state magically guarded such that an outsider could not read anything from it except its random output stream, and ensured that any bytes read by any entity could not be read by any other?  I can certainly appreciate that a TRNG has the advantage of not *having* any state that could be gleaned by an outside entity, but what difference is there otherwise?

Comment: @supercat I don't think it's necessarily an advantage that TRNGs don't have an internal state it needs to keep secret - mainly because TRNGs use environmental data to produce random output, so if you have physical access/control over the environment you can affect the output in some way (just as you might predict the output if you could get that seed data).

Comment: @deed02392: With a TRNG, if you can ensure that it isn't being actively attacked "right now" [plus or minus a few milliseconds or so] you can be sure that any data you're getting out is random and secret.  With a PRNG, you would need to know that the private state has *never* been exposed to outside observation since it was created; for some kinds of generator you would also have to know that the state *will never be* exposed.